# How to pass input value to string variable?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to allow users to specify the height and width of an iframe. I would like to allow them to enter a height and width which would populate those values in a string wich they could copy and paste.  I'm not sure how to pass that value to the string.

```
<form id="embed-customize" action="/" style="display:block">
    <fieldset class="embed-size">
    <legend>Size:</legend>
    <div>
    <input id="embed-width" type="text" value="300">
    x
    <input id="embed-height" type="text" value="500">
    </div>
    </fieldset>

</form>
<textarea id="embed-url" rows="3" cols="100"></textarea>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
var embedWidth = "";
var embedHeight = "";
var iframe = "";

jQuery('#embedWidth').blur(function(){
  embedWidth = jQuery(this).val();
})

var iframe = '<iframe width = ' + embedWidth + 'px height = ' + embedHeight +'px frameborder = "0" scrolling = "no" src = "http://www.example.com">"></iframe>';
jQuery('#embed-url').val(iframe);
})
</script>
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The code for an iframe so users can embed it on their site.

Comment: Secondly. your input id is `embed-width` but in the javascript your using `#embedWidth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot
http://jsfiddle.net/9zsqQ/

Your input id was not consistent. In the HTML it is `#embed-width` but in the javascript your using  `#embedWidth`.

Secondly your iframe code had spaces between the atribute name and the value, and some were not wrapped in double quotes. It should have been something like this:

`var iframe = '<iframe width="' + embedWidth + 'px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com">"></iframe>';`

Updated the jsfiddle so that it works for both inputs: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9zsqQ/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#embed-width').blur(function(){
  embedWidth = jQuery(this).val();
  var iframe = '<iframe width = ' + embedWidth + 'px height = ' + embedHeight +'px frameborder = "0" scrolling = "no" src = "http://www.example.com">"></iframe>';
  jQuery('#embed-url').val(iframe);
 });
})
```

Comment: No wonder it wasn't working. You have assigned the id as 'embed-width' but in the jquery selector 'embedWidth' was being used. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This would limit me to only the width and not the height though, right?

Comment: Yes. If u need the change in height jus adapt the current version to check for change in height